# Can't print out in both english and cyrillic in my C++ MFC application

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

Im writing a MFC application. I need to use the CString class not something else. I've done the following because it was the only way I could display cyrillic. Without I either got question marks or nothing showed up at all.

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

So this works:

```
CString strTestObj2("дададада");
wprintf(L"%s", strTestObj2);
```

But this doesn't:

```
CString strTestObj1("String1.");
printf("%s", strTestObj1);
```

It gives a runtime error. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You should use wide string everywhere, that is `L"дадада"` and not mix in char functions, such as `printf`

Comment: You have to change the mode back, if you want to use `printf` again. Call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);` Or just use `CStringW strTestObj2(L"дададада English");` with `wprintf`

Comment: `CString` isn't a class. It's a typedef for a class template instantiation. Since we don't know your project configuration, we cannot see what `CString` really is, though both calls to `wprintf` and `printf` are wrong. They expect one particular encoding, but you aren't providing a type that transparently between different encodings. Use `CStringW` instead.

Comment: You should be getting correct output, no matter your system's locale, if you have formatted your unicode string correctly (all unicode characters). Also, you should be getting correct output if you have formatted your MBCS string correctly in the cyrillic codepage (1251), both for English (chars<128) and Cyrillic (chars>=128), as long as your system's default copepage is Cyrillic (set the "Language for non-Unicode Programs" option - this is not necessarily the same as the UI language). By using a MBCS string you won't be getting West-European,East-European,Greek,Turkish etc characters though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by setting the OS system locale to bulgarian.